# Differentiating an integral using dominated convergence

Tags: analysis, integration

Let's say we have

$$F(x)=\int^b_af(x,t)\ \mathrm{dt}$$

And we want to calculate $F'(x)$. Then:

$$F'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{a}^{b}f(x+h,t)\mathrm{dt}-\int_{a}^{b}f(x,t)}{h}\mathrm{dt}=\lim_{h\to0}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x+h,t)-f(x,t)}{h}\mathrm{dt}\tag1$$

Now, in class we were given (without proof) the proposition that $F'(x)=\int^b_a\frac{df}{dx}(x,t)\ \mathrm{dt}$ under certain conditions, one of which is that $\frac{df}{dx}(x,t)$ be dominated by some integrable function $g(t)$.

If I could just commute the $\lim$ and the $\int$ in $(1)$, I could prove this proposition. In order to justify that, I need to find an integrable $g(t)$ such that:

$$\frac{f(x+h,t)-f(x,t)}{h}\leq g(t)$$

in a neighborhood of $0$ (right?). This seems very similary to the requirement we learned in class, but how is the boundedness of $\frac{df}{dx}(x,t)$ equivalent to the boundedness of the above? All I can see is that as $h\to0$, the difference quotient is *pointwise* eventually smaller than $g$. But I don't see that I can conclude that there is therefore a neighborhood of $0$ where the difference quotient is bounded by $g$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, there is, for each $t$, a $c_t(x) \in (0,1)$ with

$$\frac{f(x+h,t) - f(x,t)}{h} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x + c_t(x)\cdot h, t).$$

So if the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is locally uniformly (in $x$) dominated by $g$, then so are the difference quotients. And that makes the dominated convergence theorem applicable.

Comment: In all of this, I can't see why the partial derivative needs to be continuous with respect to $x$, yet that's another requirement according to our lessons.

Comment: That will be used for the continuity of $F'$. The existence follows without that assumption by the domination.