# Integrating an infinite sum (statement from paper)

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

Let us work on a bounded domain $\Omega$ with Neumann BCs, with $\varphi_k$ and $\lambda_k$ being the orthonormalised eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the Neumann Laplacian. Define 
$$v(x,y) = \sum_{k \geq 0} e^{-\lambda_k^{\frac 12} y}(u,\varphi_k)\varphi_k(x)$$
which is a sum such that the partial sums converges in $L^2(\Omega)$ for all $y \in (0,\infty)$. It holds that $v \in C^\infty((0,\infty);H^1(\Omega))$.

In [this paper, proof of Theorem 2.1](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.7406v3.pdf), the authors write the statement
$$\int_\Omega v_{yy}(y)\psi(y) = \sum_{k \geq 1} \lambda_ke^{-y\lambda_k^{\frac 12}}(u,\varphi_k)\psi_k(y)$$
given $\psi \in H^1(\Omega \times (0,\infty))$ with $\psi(x,y) = \sum_{k \geq 0}\psi_k(y)\varphi_k(x).$

**Question**: how to prove that statement? If we can differentiate the sum that defines $v$ term by term it is trivial, but I don't see why the uniform continuity of the partial sums holds. So I think there must be something else to do with the inner product in $L^2$ so that such uniform convergence may not be required, but not sure how it's rigorously done.

*Edit*: posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210336/differentiating-and-integrating-an-infinite-series-arising-from-a-pde.

Comment: (Somehow I cannot write dollars on the keyboard...?) But you mean \int_\Omega v_{yy}(x,y)\psi(x,y)dx

Comment: Also, then this follow by first computing v_yy and then use orthogonality.

Comment: @AD. Well I just left out the $x$. Regarding your second comment, that is precisely the issue, how do you compute $v_{yy}$ -- differentiating term by term? If so that needs to be justified.

Comment: This is usually done with dominated convergence, in my experience. Cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522996/differentiating-an-integral-using-dominated-convergence and apply it to the case of integration with respect to counting measure.

Comment: @Ian So do you mean that to show $y \mapsto v(y)$ (and also $y \mapsto v_{yy}(y)$) is continuous, I write $v$ as an integral wrt. a counting measure and try to apply the theorem of the thread you linked?

Comment: I think I'll have difficulty trying to bound $\lambda_k^{\frac 12}e^{-\lambda_k^{\frac 12}y}(u,\varphi_k)\varphi_k(x)$ by a summable function of $x$.

Comment: At a glance it looks like that will arise from Cauchy-Schwarz. I'm not sure if merely the fact that the eigenvalues blow up will be enough, though.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it a little bit more, I think you may need to know something about the spacing of $\lambda_k$, because if $a_n$ is a sufficiently slowly increasing, divergent sequence then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{-a_n}$ need not converge. (The example I came up with was $a_n=\log(n)$). So you might have trouble showing that $\lambda_k^{1/2} e^{-\lambda_k^{1/2} y} \in \ell^2(dk)$, i.e. that it is square summable in $k$).

Comment: @Ian if you use Cauchy-Schwarz, why would $(u,\varphi_k)\varphi_k(x)$ be square summable?